# Running a script in the script folder

Tags: linux, bash, visual-studio-code

`In Visual Studio Code, when I write a bash script (with the first line "#!/bin/bash") and click Alt+X, the script runs, however, its working folder is not the folder of the script itself, it's the working folder of the project.
How can I tell VS Code to cd to the script folder before running it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner). To help others struggling with the same issue, here is a complete solution.

1. Make sure you have the "Code Runner" extension installed.
2. Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings (or click Ctrl+,).
3. Search for the setting "fileDirectoryAsCwd".
4. Click the checkbox.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

It is not foolproof, but I generally use:

```
myname=${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
mydir=$(dirname "$myname")
cd "$mydir"
```

There are some issues with links and sourcing the file, therefore I say it is not fool-proof.

Comment: But then I have to insert these lines into each script... Isn't there a way to configure VS code to always cd to the right folder automatically?